# Is it usual for a payer's CPA to ask (demand) that I verify amounts on the 1099 he just issued me?

Tags: united-states, taxes, accounting, form-1099, tax-professionals

I do $4000 to $5000 worth of consulting work annually for a small 503(c) non-profit. They sent me my yearly 1099-MISC last week. A few days after I received it, the CPA that handles their books emailed me to ask if the amounts on my 1099-MISC were accurate. I told him politely that I didn't have immediate access to the records I needed but would be gathering everything for taxes soon. A few days later (yesterday) he wrote and said:

> *Your confirmation is needed by tomorrow to avoid delays in preparing 1099s and 1096s for other recipients.*

No other 1099 payer has ever asked, and then demanded, verification of their 1099 data like this, certainly not by the next day, and not under pressure to avoid delaying fellow vendors' tax documents. This guy's an eccentric volunteer, and everyone seems to find him annoying, but he's a CPA in the financial district in San Francisco by day and has been for decades. He must understand the job.

Is this as weird as it seems on its face, or am I missing something?

Comment: Sure it's unusual.  But honestly, **most non-profits keep less than rigorous books**, so the other volunteers might have fed him dodgy numbers.  Thus, while unusual, it still might be a completely valid request.

Comment: If you can't do it on the 24 hour turnaround timeline, reply with a concrete date you can do it and stick to that date.

Comment: Err... How would I really know?  I have multiple clients, and my bank account just records deposits, not who they were from, so the way I know how much I got from which client is to look at the 1099s they send me.

Comment: @jamesqf you should be creating/ keeping invoices so you know who is paying you what and can track if you've been paid or not.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, this is a good thing.  They're double-checking and making sure, and that is a good thing for them to do.  Especially in a volunteer org, where -- well, let's just say volunteers *don't join to do accounting*.

So yes, I strongly encourage you to give the best response you can, with all due compassion.  It's in your interest too, to get it right.

Comment: Collectively the first three comments on my original post constituted the best answer and gave me the extra context I needed. I had taken the value of compassion and accurate tax documents as a given.